# How do I create a distant skyline near the horizon?

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-osm

I have been attempting an outdoor shot of a car going down a mountain road towards a distant city. I have been having an issue with the 'distant city' part of the project. I can't seem to find a way to show a faraway place without literally making a model city that is super far away. Anything else I try and the perspective seems off or the horizon line does not match up. Is there anything I'm missing? I tried making a massive plane underneath everything to act as the ground, but I can't seem to make a convincing horizon without making the ground huge and then blowing up my render distance. I'll attach an image of the current project with a drawing of what I am hoping for. [image: Camera view of unfinished render]

Comment: how about using an HDRI background? examples: https://www.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/hdri-environment-map-round-panorama-spherical-1015117825

Comment: Is this stylized, or more-or-less photorealistic?  Ways of doing things like forced perspective, aerial perspective, would vary....could you give some stylistic pointers?